# Spring Security Facebook customization using FacebookAuthService FacebookProfile returning null value

Tags: facebook, grails, facebook-login

I have implemented Spring security facebook plugin and it works fine with the default FacebookAuthService but when I customize it to get facebook user details by creating FacebookAuthService.groovy it gives the below error message when log in with facebook button is clicked.

**Belw is a snapshot of the FacebookUser create methond from FacebookAuthService:**

```
FacebookUser create(FacebookAuthToken token) {
        Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
        FacebookProfile fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile
        String email = fbProfile.email
        String username = fbProfile.username
        String firstName = fbProfile.firstName
        String lastName = fbProfile.lastName

        User person = new User(
                username: username,
                password: token.accessToken.accessToken, //not really necessary
                enabled: true,
                accountExpired:  false,
                accountLocked: false,
                passwordExpired: false,

                //fill with data loaded from Facebook API
                name: [firstName, lastName].join(' '),
                email: email
        )
        person.save()
        UserRole.create(person, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER'))
        UserRole.create(person, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_FACEBOOK'))
        FacebookUser fbUser = new FacebookUser(
                uid: token.uid,
                accessToken: token.accessToken.accessToken,
                accessTokenExpires: token.accessToken.expireAt,
                user: person
        )
        fbUser.save()
        return fbUser
    }
```

**The error displayed is:**

```
Error |
2015-01-11 15:15:47,948 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR [/TESTAPP].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/TESTAPP] threw exception
Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.testapp.User' on field 'email': rejected value [null]; codes [com.testapp.User.email.nullable.error.com.testapp.User.email,com.testapp.User.email.nullable.error.email,com.testapp.User.email.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.testapp.User.email.nullable.error,user.email.nullable.error.com.testapp.User.email,user.email.nullable.error.email,user.email.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.email.nullable.error,com.testapp.User.email.nullable.com.testapp.User.email,com.testapp.User.email.nullable.email,com.testapp.User.email.nullable.java.lang.String,com.testapp.User.email.nullable,user.email.nullable.com.testapp.User.email,user.email.nullable.email,user.email.nullable.java.lang.String,user.email.nullable,nullable.com.testapp.User.email,nullable.email,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [email,class com.testapp.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
- Field error in object 'com.testapp.User' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes [com.testapp.User.name.nullable.error.com.testapp.User.name,com.testapp.User.name.nullable.error.name,com.testapp.User.name.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.testapp.User.name.nullable.error,user.name.nullable.error.com.testapp.User.name,user.name.nullable.error.name,user.name.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.name.nullable.error,com.testapp.User.name.nullable.com.testapp.User.name,com.testapp.User.name.nullable.name,com.testapp.User.name.nullable.java.lang.String,com.testapp.User.name.nullable,user.name.nullable.com.testapp.User.name,user.name.nullable.name,user.name.nullable.java.lang.String,user.name.nullable,nullable.com.testapp.User.name,nullable.name,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [name,class com.testapp.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
    Line | Method
->>  145 | doCall                in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao$_create_closure4
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    814 | withTransaction       in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
|    714 | withTransaction . . . in     ''
|    144 | create                in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao
|     72 | authenticate . . . .  in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthProvider
|     58 | attemptAuthentication in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthRedirectFilter
|     46 | doFilter . . . . . .  in     ''
|     82 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1110 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

With my understanding I think facebook.userOperations().userProfile is unable to retrieve the facebook user details. 
Could anyone help me with this.Or is there anything that I am missing here?

Comment: It looks like `fbProfile.email` and `fbProfile.name` are null, thus violating `User`'s constraints. Or something...

Comment: Yes, that's possible that values provided by Facebook are `null` (for empty user, or if user don't want to share this information). You probably need a workaround, like ask user for email and name in your app, or something

Comment: Yes that is the case, facebook is returning null values for those fields. I have taken care of it and its working as expected now.
Thanks a lot for your responses.